# Open Expression Web programmatically

Tags: c#, microsoft-expression-web

Is there a way to open a .html file in Expression Web programmatically (C#) without accessing registry key?

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("EXPRWD.EXE", "C:\\File.htm");
```